# Word or idiom for most popular service/offering

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a single word or a phrase that means the most popular one of some set of service tiers/offerings? For example a service provider asks "Do you want Deluxe, Premium or Gold?" then instead of asking them back which one is the most popular,  one can simply respond with something like "Give me X" and that would imply the most popular one.

Comment: "top seller"  ... "flavor of the day" ..... might be a humorous way of putting it but it often means "special offering on the menu" etc

Comment: Your own *most popular* works well there. Are you looking for something more specific? "Give me *the special*" works sometimes and it might be correlated with popularity, but some might object on the grounds of causality. "The hottest item" works, but it might be ambiguous in a restaurant setting.

Comment: For books and related products, you can also ask for their [bestseller](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bestseller) though (strangely enough), it doesn't necessarily imply their best selling product.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options, depending on exactly what kind of popularity you're referring to.  If you want what is popular *recently*, you could say "Give me whatever is **[trendy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trendy)**.

> currently popular or fashionable

If you want what is most popular of all time, you have a few options, one of which is to do what you said and ask for what is **most popular**.

You could also say "Give me whatever is **[standard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standard)**."

> a :  regularly and widely used, available, or supplied
>
> b :  well-established and very familiar